# Can't find HTML control in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a div (id=main), it contains 15 html select controls inside and their IDs are ddl1, ddl2, ddl3, ... and so on.

Now I want to dynamically select or assign their indexes from an XML file, so I wrote this code.

```
private void readxml(string spath) {
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load(spath);
  //doc.LoadXml(spath);
  XmlNodeList xmlnodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Hedge/*");
  for (int i=1; i <= 15; i++) {
    (main.FindControl("ddl" + i) as DropDownList).SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(xmlnodes[i].InnerText);
  }
}
```

But an error is occuring here...

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It's maybe because it's not able to find the controls (HTML select controls)...
Can anyone tell me the reason or solve my problem?

Comment: You say maybe - have you debugged this, there are a number of things here that could result in a null reference error?

Comment: do you have specified `runat="server"` in `main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two thing that may have went wrong.
One is obvious

```
  (main.FindControl("ddl" + i) as DropDownList).SelectedIndex = 
            Int32.Parse(xmlnodes[i].InnerText);
```

Since you are not using asp.net dropdown list so you can not cast it into this.
So it should be

```
     (main.FindControl("ddl" + i) as HtmlSelect).SelectedIndex = 
                                                    Int32.Parse(xmlnodes[i].InnerText);
```

Another could be the attribute `runat="server"` which needs to be there if you are suing `html controls` and want to access it on C# page.

```
   <select id="Select1" runat="server">
     <option value="1" Selected="True"> Item 1 </option>
     .....
  </select>
```

Comment: You just repeated what was already written in two other answers.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes I am aware of this but it helped and is accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add `runat="server"` to the control and an `Id="ddl1"`?

Answer (score 2):

In case of such markup:

```
<div id="main" runat="server">
    <select id="ddl1" runat="server"></select>
</div>
```

The type of `ddl1` won't be DropDownList but rather HtmlSelect, so change your code to:

```
(main.FindControl("ddl" + i) as HtmlSelect).SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(xmlnodes[i].InnerText);
```

If still null error, good chance that `xmlnodes` is null meaning something went wrong loading the XML document or selecting the nodes.

Comment: thanks... but its not working still (might be something wrong in xmlnodeslist, trying to solve)